# How to delete the history of a specific user in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, history

In Empathy, when you go to history, you have the option to delete all history and not for only a specific user.

How to delete the history of a specific user in Empathy people nearby account with preserving the history of other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs from Empathy (using the telepathy library, hence the naming) are under

```
$HOME/.local/share/TpLogger/logs
```

(Note that this is a hidden directory - use the terminal or `View`->`Show Hidden Files` in Nautilus)

Logs are stored in this directory in the structure

```
ACCOUNT/USER/DATE.log
```

Delete as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The logs (since Empathy 2.31.4) are saved in `~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`.
 Take a look there, and delete the file of the specific user.